# SQL Server Reporting Services is not working

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I have installed sql server 2012 and deployed rdl files into ReportingServer,

and trying to hosting in the sharepoint 2013 foundation server . i can create

service application, but system settings were not working it says "The remote

server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

i have checked under services the "SQL Server Reporting Services Service" is started and association has done.

i can open (http://rrrlb/reportserver) reporting server from sharepoint server 2013.

please help me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running SQL 2012 + SP1? If so, this is a known issue, if SP1 is not installed correctly. Usually reinstalling SP1 resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks  Raj ! 
Yes. I have installed SP2. I am keeping data base for Sharepoint and reportingserver in one server which separate server.                                                     i.e., rrrlb is my database server for sharepoint and reportingserver.
Share point App server  is shweb20.. both server got installed Sql server and sp2.  i am getting this error when i configure shweb20. 
thanks
sankar.